# Intercept what's being written to HttpResponse.OutputStream

Tags: .net, asp.net, iis-7

I am working on a tool which audits access to existing web application. Existing app does not have any hooks in place, but my plan is to inject an `IHttpModule` by modifying web.config and log whatever I need to log during `EndRequest` event.

What I'm struggling with right now is: I cannot intercept what is application writing to an output stream. I need to know what output does the application send to the client. Originally, I hoped I could run a code in `BeginRequest` to replace `HttpContext.Response.OutputStream` with a stream of my own, which would be flushed to original stream during `EndRequest`, but the stream only has a `get` accessor, so I cannot replace it.

I could of course use reflection to assign to private member of `HttpContext`.

Can anyone here think of a better way to tee up contents of what is being written to a given stream?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out Response.Filter.

http://www.west-wind.com/Weblog/ShowPost.aspx?id=72596&utm_source=feedburner&utm_medium=feed&utm_campaign=Feed%3A+koistya+%28RIA+Guy+%7C+Web+Development+News%29

Answer (score 1):

See this article for an example of how to implement a response filter: http://aspnetresources.com/articles/HttpFilters.aspx